How to declare type of props in vuejs with typescript?
Here's the snippet of code
<tr v-for="(log, index) in logs">
        <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.timestamp }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.logType }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.logMessage }}</td>
      </tr>



defineProps({
  logs: {
    type: [Array],
    required: true
  }
})

Here log would be
{ timestamp : "2024-05-07 08:51:06",
logType : "INFO",
logMessage : "mailbox allocated for rsvp"
}

I'm new to typescript and I'm getting the below warning for log.timestamp, log.logType and log.logMessage during build
'log' is of type 'unknown'.
What should be the type of logs here?

Assuming log is of type
type LogEntry = {
  timestamp: string;
  logType: string;
  logMessage: string;
};

as answered in your previous question.
You can do it
const props = defineProps({
  logs: {
    type: Array as PropType<Array<LogEntry>>,
    required: true,
  },
});

Don't forget to import PropType.
import type { PropType } from 'vue';

Docs
If you didn't have a type/interface for some reason you could declare it straight away like
logs: {
    type: Array as PropType<Array<{timestamp: string, logType: string, logMessage: string}>>,
    required: true,
  },

